# Cannot access property of class

Tags: c#, class, properties, nested

I am writing some generic classes that i'd like to use in some of my apps. For example this socket class:

```
public class jSocket
{
    public class Server
    {
        public static _Settings Settings = new _Settings();
        public class _Settings
        {
            private int _Listen;
            public int Listen
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Listen;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Listen = value;
                }
            }

            private int _Port;
            public int Port
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_Port == 0)
                        _Port = 1337;
                    return _Port;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Port = value;
                }
            }

            private IPEndPoint _localEndPoint;
            public IPEndPoint localEndPoint
            {
                get
                {
                    if(_localEndPoint == null)
                        _localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Tools.getLocalIPAddress(), Port);
                    return _localEndPoint;
                }
                set
                {
                    _localEndPoint = value;
                }
            }
      }

      public void Start()
      {
           //Do work
      }
}
```

Now in my application i instantiate the class:

```
jSocket.Server newServ = new jComp.jSocket.Server();
```

But why can't I access the Properties of Settings? What I want to do is this:

```
newServ.Settings.Port = 1001;
```

Do I need to write constructors for every field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Setting` field is `static`, you need to remove `static` and make it an instance field.So then it will belong to your instance and you will be able to access it.

```
public _Settings Settings = new _Settings();
```